# Not able to remove some field in logstash.conf

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I want to delete `otherString` field. I have tried but no impact.

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => "5000"
  }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => {"message" => "{\"serviceName\":\"%{DATA:indexName}\",\"%{DATA:otherString\"}}"}
    }
    json {
      source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => ["message", "otherString"]
      add_field => { "[@metadata][index_name]" => "%{indexName}" }
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
     index => "%{[@metadata][index_name]}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
         "@timestamp" => 2019-03-26T12:43:45.628Z,
              "level" => "info",
             "userId" => "bbs234isad2i3h4isand",
          "indexName" => "bff_web",
      "otherString\\" => "datetime\":\"2019-02-02 18:13:45:311\",\"userId\":\"bbs234isad2i3h4isand\",\"apiName\":\"/v1/admin/deposit/purpose\",\"apiResponseTime\":3692,\"accessedTables\":[\"-\"],\"userIP\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"reqParam\":{",
    "apiResponseTime" => 3692,
          "reqMethod" => "POST",
               "port" => 565656,
        "serviceName" => "bff_web",
            "apiName" => "/v1/admin/deposit/purpose",
           "@version" => "1",
             "userIP" => "127.0.0.1",
               "file" => "/Users/private/Desktop/arjun-git/bff-web/cashiers.server.controller.js",
              "label" => "/usr/local/bin/node",
     "accessedTables" => [
        [0] "-"
    ],
               "line" => "4972",
           "reqParam" => {},
               "host" => "2.2.2.2",
           "datetime" => "2019-02-02 18:13:45:311"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your field name is "otherString\", which is not the same as "otherString". Could you try either fixing the way you name that field in the first place or adapt the mutate filter to match that specific field name?

Comment: I tried this `remove_field => ["message", "otherString\"]` but grok not match exception coming. I don't know why \ (slash) sign coming in the key

Comment: You named your field with a "\" at the end...%{DATA:otherString\"}. Just change it to "%{DATA:otherString}